# Three js code hints / auto complete?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, autocomplete, three.js, editor

I am looking for a free editor that will support code hints/auto complete for THREE js.

Preferably a plugin for notepad++ but I will try just about any IDE that is free. I have heard that sublime 2 supports it but I want something I can use for free.

Also, I have tried to use Tern for Eclipse but for the life of me I can not get it to work.

Does anyone know of a good THREEjs editor or some magic way to get tern to work properly in Eclipse (using Latest Eclipse Java EE distribution)?

Comment: You can try the bracket editor. It is open source editor, it will helpful for you . Link : http://brackets.io/

Comment: I will give it a try and update when I have tested it.

Comment: What is your problem with tern & Eclipse?

Comment: The part of your question about finding some editor is OT on this site. As for the problems with tern you need to include what/how exactly isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Editors

JavaScript editors are more useful to develop the scripting very quickly .

According to your question we may develop the three js by using Bracket IDE(as i mentioned in comment). But look into the Atom.io editor also. Atom is similar to Bracket but it has some more features than bracket.

## Performance

Sublime is written in **C**, which makes it fast. Atom, as well as Brackets, are developed on a **node+webkit platform** .

> Atom has its own custom version called **"atom-shell"** which means that they both are nothing more than just an advanced webapp and because of that - they will never be as fast as Sublime.

Atom and Bracket supports more language , even Atom is supported many language more than bracket too.

### Links :

[Atom Editor Link](https://atom.io/)

[Bracket Editor Link](http://brackets.io/)

Happy Coding.. !

Answer (score 0):

[brackets.io](http://brackets.io/) has out of box support for THREE js. Downloaded and working in 5min.

If you are doing anything with Three js and want something free and super easy with auto complete support this is a great editor.

Thank you vinohd for the link.

Comment: cool.  I have updated the answer too. It will helpful more to you.. Think about performance also.. Look into that. Lemme know your thoughts.

Comment: I don't see any out of the box support for three.js in brackets